# Uib-typeahead not displaying results

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to get uib-typeahead to show a list of addresses and am having trouble writing the loop for it.

Controller function:

```
$scope.addresses = function(address) {
    $http.get(config
    .apiUrl +
    'addressvalidation/validateaddress?address1=' +
    address).then(function (response) {
        //alert(response.data.matchedAddressResults[0].formattedAddress);
        return response.data.matchedAddressResults;
    });
};
```

matchedAddressResults is an array of objects (ex. "address":"123 anywhere st.")

Typeahead code:

```
uib-typeahead="item as item.address for item in addresses($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue:startsWith | limitTo:8"
                       typeahead-min-length="12">
```

How can I correctly write the loop?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. **return** $http.get(...)

Comment: That was it, thanks!